# `Object does not support this action` when adding element to div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a table to div via javascript:

```
var panel = document.getElementById("panel1");
var tbl="<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Title</th></tr><tr><td><input type='text' id='Name' name='Name' /></td><td><input type='text' id='Title' name='Title' /></td></tr></table>";
panel.innerHTML(tbl);
```

But the last line `panel.innerHTML(tbl)` is giving me an error `Object does not support this action.

P.S. I cannot use JQuery, must use JavaScript

Comment: jquery is javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use it as a `setter`.

```
panel.innerHTML = tbl;
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
panel.innerHTML = tbl;
```